# Reverse-i-search (ctrl+r) not working after MacOS Monterey update - bsdthread_register error

Tags: macos-monterey

I updated my MacOS to Monterey and since then the reverse-i-search (ctrl + r) throws the following error:

```
fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x115b9ca, 0x21)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.3/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:616 +0x81 fp=0x7ff7bfefef58 sp=0x7ff7bfefef38 pc=0x10271b1
runtime.goenvs()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.3/libexec/src/runtime/os_darwin.go:129 +0x83 fp=0x7ff7bfefef88 sp=0x7ff7bfefef58 pc=0x1024d33
runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.3/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:501 +0xd6 fp=0x7ff7bfefeff0 sp=0x7ff7bfefef88 pc=0x1029aa6
runtime.rt0_go(0x7ff7bfeff028, 0x1, 0x7ff7bfeff028, 0x0, 0x1000000, 0x1, 0x7ff7bfeff2e0, 0x0, 0x7ff7bfeff2e4, 0x7ff7bfeff320, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.3/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:252 +0x1f4 fp=0x7ff7bfefeff8 sp=0x7ff7bfefeff0 pc=0x104f9b4
```

The error is thrown on both the Mac terminal and iTerm2. Shell is zsh.

Any ideas to fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix was to upgrade brew packages through:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Not sure which package was the culprit but issue fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had `fzf` installed working with <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> so I was able to fix my manifestation of this issue with:

- `brew reinstall fzf`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this may help you: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MacOS12BSDThreadRegisterIssue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).